# getting data from a scrape on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to software development and am trying to build a fullstack javascript app on my own.

I currently am running a scrape with cheerio in express, as follows:

```
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
//do things.
})
```

I will be using Angular for the front end. 
How do I do the scrape whenever a user visits my home page/root route, so that I have data to compare against their inputs in angular? assume that the home page is at '/'.

this is what my angular app.js looks like so far:

```
angular.module('FFTrades', [
    'FFTrades.services',
    'ngRoute'

]).config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/tradeanalyzer/tradeanalyzer.html',
    controller: 'TradesController'
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use a `.run` module.  These are run automatically when your app starts up.

And add your scrap data to a `service` or the `$rootScope`.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.hello = function() {
    console.log('hello');  
  }
});
```

*If you are new to angular you might run into some issues getting the result from the scrape `promise` and applying it to the `$scope`.  These would be new questions, but above should answer the particular question you are looking for.*

Answer (score 1):

app.run will help you to check your url

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $cookies, $location, $http) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if (next.originalPath != '/') {
        console.log('inside your home page');
    }
    });
});
```